# inserting unchecked array checkbox variable into database

Tags: php, database, forms, checkbox

I have a form now which goes through a for loop that loop through accordingly the number of times the options I want it to appear.

Here's the code for it:

```
<?php for ($i =1; $i <=20; $i++) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td><center><input type="text" name="qnsNo[]" class="qnsNo"/></center></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="question[]" class="question"/></td>
                    <td><select name="input[]" class="dropdown">
                            <option value="Normal text line, no input required*">Normal text line, no input required*</option>
                            <option value="Multiple choice (only one answer) [Radio Button]">Multiple choice (only one answer) [Radio Button]</option>
                            <option value="Multiple choice (multiple answers) [Check box]">Multiple choice (multiple answers) [Check box]</option>
                            <option value="Drop-Down Box">Drop-Down Box</option>
                            <option value="Comment/Essay Box [Textarea]">Comment/Essay Box [Textarea]</option>
                            <option value="Single Line Textbox">Single Line Textbox</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="options[]" class="option"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="others[]" class="others"/></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="compulsory[]" value=""/>
                    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="compulsory[]" value="Compulsory"/></center></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

What this form actually does is to allow people to create their own form, for the last column "Compulsory field?" allow them to choose whether this question they want it compulsory or not. But current I can't seems to insert the checkbox result correctly into the database.

I hear that if you want to insert an unchecked checkbox answer into database, you can put hidden field before the actual checkbox line.. I tried my luck putting it, the inserting part is still incorrect..
Is there any way where I can insert the value according to unchecked and checked?
Like if it's unchecked, will be 'null', if it's checked, then will insert 'Compulsory'...

In case needed, here's the code for the inserting into database:

```
$sql_array = array();
    foreach ($_POST['question'] as $row => $name) {

        $question = $name;
        $qnsNo = $_POST['qnsNo'][$row];
        $input = $_POST['input'][$row];
        $options = $_POST['options'][$row];
        $others = $_POST['others'][$row];
        $compulsory = $_POST['compulsory'][$row];

        $idQuery = "SELECT max(surveyID) FROM scSurveyForm WHERE createBy = '$createBy' AND writeUp = '$writeUp'";
        $idResult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $idQuery);
        $rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($idResult);
        $lastID = $rows[0];

        $sql_array[] = "('" . $question . "'," . $lastID . ",'" . $qnsNo . "','" . $input . "','" . $options . "','" . $others . "','" . $compulsory . "')";

        if (!empty($question)) {

            $query_single = "INSERT INTO scFormLayout(question, surveyID, qnsNo, input, options, others, compulsory)
  VALUES" . implode(', ', $sql_array);
            echo $query_single.'<br/>';
            $status = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_single);
            $sql_array = array();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add number to name of your checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="compulsory[<?php echo $i; ?>]" ... >
```

and test if checkbox exists in `$_POST`

```
// you get 'on' or NULL
$compulsory = isset($_POST['compulsory'][$row]) ? $_POST['compulsory'][$row] : NULL;
```

or shorter:

```
// you get TRUE or FALSE
$compulsory = isset($_POST['compulsory'][$row]);
```